# How to set the vertical alignment in FormLayout

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Is there a way to set the vertical alignment of the components within a FormLayout row? In the example below, the field with the green background should be aligned to the top and not the center of the row.

[image: FormLayout with two rows. The field with the green background is in the first cell of the second row.]

Comment: The issue comes always up, if I added a CustomField to the FormLayout. In this case the component is always centered.

Comment: are you trying to align Neues Passwort and Kantineneinschränkung with the Berechtigungen text? or relative to some other field?

Comment: I changed the image in the first post. It is not possible to change the alsign of the green field. I have to set the align of the FormLayout. But there is unfortunately no possiblity to do it.

Comment: one alternative could be to insert those bottom components into a HorizontalLayout instead, add that layout to the view, and then set alignments within that layout

Comment: But if I add the components on a HorizonalLayout I do not have all the benefits regarding layouting. Currently depening on parameter, some fields are shown and some not but with the FormLayout I do not have empty spaces. There are a lot of fields more which are not shown on the screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried following `greenComponent.getElement().getStyles().set("align-self","flex-start")`

Comment: Unfortunately this has no effext. The green component is still centered.